# How can I install mpmath as an external library for Blender?

Tags: blender, sympy, mpmath

I'm interested in trying out sympy with Blender (v2.76, Python 3.4.2 Console, Windows 8.1). I followed this [answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/15453/error-import-point3d-of-geometry-module-of-sympy0-7-5-in-blender2-71/15513#15513) from Blender SE, downloaded sympy as a ZIP from Githib, and moved the sympy folder to C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.76\python\lib\site-packages. However, when I opened Blender and tried to import sympy in the Python Console, I got the following error:

```
>>> import sympy
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<blender_console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.76\python\lib\site-packages\sympy\__init__.py", line 20, in <module>
    raise ImportError("SymPy now depends on mpmath as an external library. "
ImportError: SymPy now depends on mpmath as an external library. See http://docs.sympy.org/latest/install.html#mpmath for more information.
```

I don't know how to install an external library. I tried going to the [link](http://docs.sympy.org/latest/install.html#mpmath) mentioned in the ImportError, and I saw `pip install mpmath`. I tried it in cmd, but got this:

```
>pip install mpmath
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): mpmath in c:\anaconda3
\lib\site-packages
```

I did install Anaconda a while ago, so I guess it makes sense to have this output. How can I install mpmath as an external library for Blender so I can import sympy in it?

Comment: Like sympy you want mpmath installed into blenders python folder. You are running pip in a system installed python that knows mpmath is installed in `c:\anaconda3\....` You can also try adding that existing path to [`sys.path`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.path)

Comment: @sambler That works, thanks. When you mentioned `sys.path`, it must've been about imports, and this made much more sense to me. I found I could also download [mpmath](https://github.com/fredrik-johansson/mpmath) also from Github and copy the mpmath folder as needed. It was like the Blender SE answer, but with mpmath instead of sympy. What I found pretty cool is that since I have Anaconda installed on Windows, I can just add "c:\anaconda3
\lib\site-packages" to PYTHONPATH, and I don't need to even download anything from Github. I could delete the sympy and mpmath folders, and it still works.

Comment: @sambler I can accept your comment as an answer. Again, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to install mpmath into blenders python folder, the same as you have done for sympy.

Your example of running pip was done in a system installed python that is setup to find the mpmath that you have installed in `c:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages`

Another option is to use the existing install of mpmath and sympy by adding your existing path to [sys.path](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.path) or adding it to the `PYTHONPATH` environment variable before you start blender.